# Denying download of specific files in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a couple of files sitting in the root of my project that look like web files, but they are not: `package.json` and `gruntfile.js` for example.

Unfortunately, the user can navigate to the files in the root path.

I'd like to avoid this.  There must be way?  All of the other files in that folder aren't accessable.

Comment: Not a response, only an opinion. If you avoid access to gruntfile.js is possible that some functionality of your site won't run. Because normally the*.js files is downloaded by client navigator.

Comment: @AlbertoLeón I'm sorry.  I'm not following.  Why wouldn't functionality on my site work if I deny access to gruntfile.js?  It is not a client file.  The user should never get this particular js file.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way, would be: create 2 routes, `/package.json` and `/gruntfile.js` for controller that would respond HTTP 403.

Another, is to create a global filter, that would match those routes and respond with HTTP 403 as well.

Comment: Hmmm... I've tried both of these with no luck.  If I create a route of "gruntfile.js", it doesn't get mapped to my controller.  Likewise, if I create an "ActionFilter", `OnActionExecuting` never gets called when I request gruntfile.js.

I think ASP is doing something for these files before it ever gets to the routing/controllers subsystem.

Comment: I don't have any code yet (I'd rather not post my many failed attempts because nothing seems to work). I just have a file that I don't want to be served.  My problem can be replicated by creating a new project, adding a simple `test.js` file in the root folder, and trying to block it from being downloaded whilst keeping it in the project.